# psycopg2 dictionary dump to json

Tags: python, json, psycopg2

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I am trying to dump a psycopg2 dictionary directly into a json string.  I do get a return value in the browser, but it isn't formatted like most of the other json examples I see.  The idea being to dump the result of a select statement into a json string and unbundle it on the other end to add into a database on the client side.  The code is below and a sample of the return.  Is there a better way to do this operation with json and psycopg2?

```
    # initializing variables
    location_connection = location_cursor = 0
    sql_string = coordinate_return = data = ""

    # opening connection and setting cursor
    location_connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname='' user='' password=''")
    location_cursor = location_connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)

    # setting sql string and executing query
    sql_string = "select * from " + tablename + " where left(alphacoordinate," + str(len(coordinate)) + ") = '" + coordinate + "' order by alphacoordinate;"
    location_cursor.execute(sql_string)
    data = json.dumps(location_cursor.fetchall())

    # closing database connection
    location_connection.close()

    # returning coordinate string
    return data
```

> sample return
>
> "[{\"alphacoordinate\": \"nmaan-001-01\", \"xcoordinate\":
>   3072951151886, \"planetarydiameter\": 288499, \"planetarymass\":
>   2.020936938e+27, \"planetarydescription\": \"PCCGQAAA\", \"planetarydescriptionsecondary\": 0, \"moons\": 1"\"}]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the JSON string directly in Postgres using `row_to_json`:

```
# setting sql string and executing query
sql_string = "select row_to_json(" + tablename + ") from " + tablename + " where left(alphacoordinate," + str(len(coordinate)) + ") = '" + coordinate + "' order by alphacoordinate;"
location_cursor.execute(sql_string)
data = location_cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That appears to be better formatting for what I want to do.  Is there an easy way to unpack it on the other end?  ---------------------- [{"row_to_json":{"alphacoordinate":"nmaan-001-01","xcoordinate":3072951151886,"planetarydiameter":288499,"planetarymass":2.020936938e+27,"planetarydescription":"PCCGQAAA","planetarydescriptionsecondary":0,"moons":1,"metals":1822,"crystals":75696,"fissionables":2399,"tradegoods":850,"herbivorefoodbase":75,"carnivorefoodbase":37,"omnivorefoodbase":56,"photovorefoodbase":145919,"mineralvorefoodbase":4501,"ownernumber":"","special":""}}]